# Power Query user.zip keep getting replaced (Privacy levels, Fast Combine)

Tags: excel, powerquery

So I am maintaining a query for a coworker, and because the query need internal and external resources I have to set the privacy level inside the query options to none.

Excel 2016

Data tab > Queries & connections > right click on query > edit > file > options and settings > query options > privacy (global) > set as Always Ignore Privacy Level Settings

Now, for me this setting is persisting, every time I open the file it's there, and the version of the file does not matter either. (We keep the file in a shared folder in the network, so we both open the same file, or copy to our machines and for me the option is unchanged, for him it changes every day)

There's only one post out there I could find that pointed in the right direction but is abandoned so it don't really has the answer.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aae1f1ba-f0ac-46ee-bf59-f6241a3872db/power-query-privacy-levels-are-not-saved?forum=powerquery

The bottom line is that it seem that his user.zip file which is where this type of configuration is saved is being overwritten everyday, and I have no idea why. We both get/use the file from the same place, we are both working on VMs on the same network.

Has anyone been through this?

**After answer Edit**

The accepted answer don't really answer the original question, but the original question was a offspring of the actual problem that is the Fast Combine, which the accepted answer solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple line of VBA code to set this property for all users:

```
ThisWorkbook.Queries.FastCombine = True
```

There's more information here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gilraviv/2015/11/25/use-vba-to-enable-fast-combine-in-excel-2016/

Comment: Well, thank you so much. I doubt I would ever find it, I was not looking for anything even remotely related to Fast Combine. This did the trick like a charm, just popped in OnWorkbookOpen and it all works now.